# How to replace outlier values with nearest value, like the filloutlier function in Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, dynamic-programming

I need to replicate the [filloutliers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filloutliers.html)(someList,'nearest','mean') function that exists in Matlab.

I have the following code which works mostly correct. However, when I give it the dataset it replaces the wrong value. It replaces 453.675231 with 0 instead of -211.71818100000002. I have tried to change the `compareNeighbors` function a bunch of different ways but I am honestly quite lost at what to do at this point.

I'll add the data so that you could just copy and paste it and it should work. If I switch the < to > in the `compareNeighbors` function works for this example but not for others.

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from statistics import stdev as std

def compareNeighbors(before, current, after):
    valBefore = (before - current)
    valAfter = (after - current)

    print(valBefore)
    print(valAfter)

    return(valBefore < valAfter) 

def findNearestValue(data, before, current, after):
    before = before if before > -1 else 0
    after = after if after < len(data) else len(data) - 1

    valBefore = data[before] if before != current else 10000000000
    valAfter = data[after] if after != current else 10000000000

    return valBefore if compareNeighbors(valBefore, valAfter, data[current]) else valAfter

def getOutlierLists(data, distance):
    outlierList = []
    outlierList.extend(data[data > distance].tolist())
    outlierList.extend(data[data < -distance].tolist())

    outlierListIndecies = [i for i, j in enumerate(data) if j in outlierList]

    return(outlierList, outlierListIndecies)

def filloutliers(data):
    stad = std(data)
    mean = np.mean(data)
    distance = 3*stad + mean

    (outlierList, outlierListIndecies) = getOutlierLists(data, distance)

    print(outlierList, " | ", outlierListIndecies, " | ", distance, " | ", mean)

    for i in range(len(outlierList)):
        data[outlierListIndecies[i]] = findNearestValue(data, outlierListIndecies[i] - 1, outlierListIndecies[i], outlierListIndecies[i] + 1)

    (outlierList, outlierListIndecies) = getOutlierLists(data, distance)

    if(len(outlierList) != 0):
        for i in reversed(range(len(outlierList))):
            data[outlierListIndecies[i]] = findNearestValue(data, outlierListIndecies[i] - 1, outlierListIndecies[i], outlierListIndecies[i] + 1)

    return data
```

> Outlier value: [453.675231]
>  Position in array: [46] 
>  Max value
> for after which a value is an outlier: +/-415.67922821410116 
> Mean: 99.86239028000001
>
> Input data:
>  [0.0, 195.47146400000003, 0.0, 143.1795457,
> 19.7727047, 0.0, 37.9259413, 67.4346233, 175.714837, 140.72522700000002, 42.116339999999994, 0.0, 11.829232000000005, 0.0, 225.20435399999997, 25.939856999999996, 9.875561000000005, 0.0, 30.22819100000001, 141.658386, 191.42069600000002, 182.451406, 188.27667599999998, 0.0, 192.48585400000002, 0.0, 79.817566, 94.469158, 97.0669257, 153.0584423, 87.5491337, 0.0, 87.5491337, 0.0, 377.6008777, 176.6662877, 397.683778, 82.18773, 136.917358, 79.201378, 57.71598, 1.795560000000009, 1.795560000000009, 19.405960000000007, 135.51628, 0.0, 453.675231, 211.71818100000002, 109.460083, 13.761809999999997, 0.0, 114.462883, 7.609375, 159.630814, 9.943822999999998, 0.0, 93.460329, 55.87061700000001, 46.083324000000005, 58.686195999999995, 18.636627, 0.0, 22.810349000000002, 144.659505, 0.0, 267.669085, 290.303405, 110.52316300000001, 52.656178, 110.52316300000001, 52.656178, 123.26508600000001, 61.89890700000001, 158.23855600000002, 194.428161, 181.365445, 264.36523, 0.0, 274.60668, 48.543030000000016, 308.51727600000004, 357.209626, 24.18412, 46.621155, 70.805275, 181.781889, 364.741453, 0.0, 143.62354900000003, 0.0, 4.201691000000004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 135.2808976, 87.3988186, 216.920091, 84.215256, 161.518512, 0.0]
>
> Output data:
>  [0.0, 195.47146400000003, 0.0, 143.1795457,
> 19.7727047, 0.0, 37.9259413, 67.4346233, 175.714837, 140.72522700000002, 42.116339999999994, 0.0, 11.829232000000005, 0.0, 225.20435399999997, 25.939856999999996, 9.875561000000005, 0.0, 30.22819100000001, 141.658386, 191.42069600000002, 182.451406, 188.27667599999998, 0.0, 192.48585400000002, 0.0, 79.817566, 94.469158, 97.0669257, 153.0584423, 87.5491337, 0.0, 87.5491337, 0.0, 377.6008777, 176.6662877, 397.683778, 82.18773, 136.917358, 79.201378, 57.71598, 1.795560000000009, 1.795560000000009, 19.405960000000007, 135.51628, 0.0, 0.0, 211.71818100000002, 109.460083, 13.761809999999997, 0.0, 114.462883, 7.609375, 159.630814, 9.943822999999998, 0.0, 93.460329, 55.87061700000001, 46.083324000000005, 58.686195999999995, 18.636627, 0.0, 22.810349000000002, 144.659505, 0.0, 267.669085, 290.303405, 110.52316300000001, 52.656178, 110.52316300000001, 52.656178, 123.26508600000001, 61.89890700000001, 158.23855600000002, 194.428161, 181.365445, 264.36523, 0.0, 274.60668, 48.543030000000016, 308.51727600000004, 357.209626, 24.18412, 46.621155, 70.805275, 181.781889, 364.741453, 0.0, 143.62354900000003, 0.0, 4.201691000000004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 135.2808976, 87.3988186, 216.920091, 84.215256, 161.518512, 0.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only for this specific usecase where you need to fill the outliers with the nearest values which is 3 standard deviations away from the mean.

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from statistics import stdev as std

def isNotOutlier(point, upper, lower):
    return (point < upper and point > lower)

def findNearestValue(data, before, current, after, threshAbove, threshBelow):
    before = before if before > -1 else 0
    after = after if after < len(data) else len(data) - 1


    while(True):
        if(after < len(data) and isNotOutlier(data[after],threshAbove,threshBelow)):
            return data[after]
        after += 1
        if(before >= 0 and isNotOutlier(data[before],threshAbove,threshBelow)):
            return data[before]
        before -= 1


def getOutlierLists(data, distancePos, distanceNeg):
    outlierList = []
    outlierList.extend(data[data > distancePos].tolist())
    outlierList.extend(data[data < distanceNeg].tolist())

    outlierListIndecies = [i for i, j in enumerate(data) if j in outlierList]

    return(outlierList, outlierListIndecies)

def filloutliers(data):
    stad = std(data)
    mean = np.mean(data)
    distancePos = 3*stad + mean
    distanceNeg = (-3*stad) + mean

    (outlierList, outlierListIndecies) = getOutlierLists(data, distancePos, distanceNeg)
    
    toReplace =[]

    for i in range(len(outlierList)):
        toReplace.append(findNearestValue(data, outlierListIndecies[i] - 1, outlierListIndecies[i], outlierListIndecies[i] + 1, distancePos, distanceNeg))

    for i in range(len(outlierListIndecies)):
        data[outlierListIndecies[i]] = toReplace[i]
        
    return data
```